# 'React Native' select location using native maps

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-maps

I need user to select location of an event.

Now what already works is opening the native maps (at least on android) - I can open the native maps through `{ Linking } from "react-native";` `geo:24.669026,24.699024?z=6`

However what I can't find how to make native maps prompt user to set some location and after some kind of confirmation?

I imagined something like `return_url` with some sort of backlink to my application.

Or is this ONLY possible through embeding maps and using Google Maps API?

(I am trying to avoid billing, since all I want to do is to help user to find the coordinates and put them back to application, the application doesn't use the coordinates to do anything besides sending user to display them on they native maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if I understood you correctly you want to show the user's current location on the map without paying to any third party, if that's the case you need to do the followings.

1. Get user latitude and longitude.
2. Show those latitudes and longitudes on the map using some marker.

**1. Get user latitude and longitude.**

You can follow the below article for getting user latitude and longitude.

- ReactNative: https://aboutreact.com/react-native-geolocation/
- Expo: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location

**2. Show those latitudes and longitudes on the map using some marker.**

So in this step, we will be using `react-native-maps` and `OpenStreetMap`.

*Note: Do not change `urlTemplate` in the `UrlTile`*

Here is the reference for custom map tile from `react-native-maps`

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#tile-overlay-using-tile-server

```
import MapView, { UrlTile, Marker } from "react-native-maps";

const { width, height } = props;
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 8; //Very high zoom level
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;
const userCoords={{
   latitude: number,
   longitude: number
}};
<MapView
  initialRegion={{
    latitude: 51.1657,
    longitude: 10.4515,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  }}
  loadingEnabled
  minZoomLevel={3}
  maxZoomLevel={10}
  showsIndoors={false}
  showsTraffic={false}
  showsBuildings={false}
  showsScale={true}
>
  <UrlTile
    /**
     * The url template of the tile server. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
     * For example, http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
     */
    urlTemplate={"http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}
    /**
     * The maximum zoom level for this tile overlay. Corresponds to the maximumZ setting in
     * MKTileOverlay. iOS only.
     */
    maximumZ={10}
    /**
     * flipY allows tiles with inverted y coordinates (origin at bottom left of map)
     * to be used. Its default value is false.
     */
    flipY={false}
  />
  <Marker coordinate={userCoords}>
    /**
     * Your custom marker here 
    */
  </Marker>
</MapView>;
```

Comment: I want user to pick location on a map and get that location, I don't want to just display location on map and I don't want to get current user location (I already know how to do both without billing).

Comment: BTW: if openstreetmap.org can do deep link back to application with selected coordinates - I'm not against that :-)

Comment: @jave.web yeah of course you can do so with `react-native-maps` follow this link https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#mapview-events

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they support openstreetmap too, awesome, and although this A does not answer the original question, it provides a solution to the initiating problem :-) I think you've got the essence from the question even though I may have asked it in a too specific way.

Comment: Even though I've added the `UrlTile` unchanged, I still see the Google logo in bottom right of the map - is there more to set up for react-native-maps touse openstreetmap? (otherwise I could get the coordinates with `onPress` on the `MapView`, no deeplinking needed)

Comment: Also the docs say it's and "overlay"? So it's still required to have google maps API Key?

Comment: I don't think so I'm already using this in an app and it works fine for both platforms but `google play services` are necessary on Android phones but for a while now it comes up by default with phones.

Comment: And that's correct you will see the Google logo on Android and Apple logo on iOS devices that's because it uses the device map.

Comment: OK, thanks, and do you happen to know if there's some API key needed to be set-up (and where?) (I know this is offtopic but you seem to've worked with it)

Comment: There is no need for this!

Comment: Strange, it says here https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#troubleshooting "Make sure you have enabled Google Maps API in Google developer console"

Comment: That's true when you are not using open source map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243561/discussion-between-jave-web-and-ali-hussnain).

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't do that with `react-native`, you have to add your own map. You can use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps)

Comment: and is it even possible outside of react native? (in e.g. a native android app?)

Comment: On android you can create an `Intent`, but I'm not sure whether google maps provides anything to handle intents like you need. But it probably is possible going native.